# Exclude folders with new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer().FileSystem.CopyDirectory( sourceFolder, outputFolder );

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

Is it possible to exclude folders with new

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer().
    FileSystem.CopyDirectory( sourceFolder, outputFolder );
```

This will copy the entire contents from the source to the target, but let's say I don't want to copy certain folders, is there a way to exclude those.

Answer (score 0):

Using Reflector there doesn't seem to be any public (or private for that matter) hooks in the `CopyDirectory` code to allow for some folders or files to be skipped when copying.

It looks like you'll have to redo the recursive `CreateDirectory` and `CopyFile` loops yourself, adding the hooks to check conditions that skip files or folders.

And note the `Directory` and `DirectoryInfo` `EnumerateFiles` and `EnumerateDirectories` overloads (new to .NET Framework 4.0) that may allow you to select the folders (or files) by pattern match, and otherwise by using Linq.

Also note that the `CopyDirectory` code is all in `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, so C# devotees who don't want to include that assembly/namespace would have already had to cut code for copying a directory tree, so you might find some samples that just need conversion to VB.NET.